# Insert metadata Flowise + pinecone

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, pinecone, flowise

I am trying to do an upsert in Pinecone using Flowise. As I need to do this for several PDF files, I am using the 'Folder with Files' node. So far so good, but I have the need to insert as metadata a part of the file names. These files follow the standard naming convention: XXXXX-XXXXX Name, with X being numbers. Is there a way to do this in Flowise?

I was able to add metadata, but not in a dynamic way.